# 2-generated finite non-Abelian simple groups and the existence of Hamiltonian cycles in their Cayley graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finitely-generated, simple-groups, cayley-graphs

Given that $G = \langle a, b\rangle$ and that $a$ is an involution, when is it the case that there exists $c, d$ such that $G = 
\langle c, d\rangle$ and $cd$ is an involution?

---

At present, I am reviewing the [following paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X09000776) by I. Pak and R. Radoičić (2009), to include their main result in my undergraduate dissertation (which is a survey on the Hamiltonicity of Cayley graphs and digraphs). This result is stated as follows:

> **Theorem 1** Every finite group $G$ of size $|G| \geq 3$ has a generating set $S$ of size $|S| \leq \log_2 |G|$, such that the corresponding Cayley graph $\Gamma(G, S)$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

The proof relies on a further theorem given in the paper, which I shall also state. Firstly, note that $r(G)$ and $m(G)$ denote that number of Abelian and non-Abelian composition factors of $G$.

> **Theorem 2** Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $r(G)$ and $m(G)$ be as above. Then there exists a generating set $S$, $\langle S \rangle = G$, with $|S| \leq r(G) + 2m(G)$, such that the corresponding Cayley graph $\Gamma(G, S)$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

While I do understand the way with which **Theorem 1** follows from **Theorem 2**, the proof for **Theorem 2** is not clear to me. Firstly, it is worth noting that the proof relies on consequences of the Classification of Finite Simple Groups; namely that "*every non-Abelian finite simple group can be generated by two elements, one of which is an involution*".

No reference is given in the paper to a proof of the aforementioned remark. I have however found the [following paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869317300273) by C. S. H. King (2016), in which the author proves that, indeed, every non-Abelian finite simple group is generated by an involution and an element of prime order. Of course, given the survey nature of the dissertation (and that it is at undergraduate level), this result will be simply stated. However, the aim is to clarify for non-expert readers the proofs given by Pak and Radoičić in [[1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X09000776)], and I think stating this reference [[2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869317300273)] will help do so.

The second result that comes into play in the proof of **Theorem 2** is one given by [R. A. Rankin (1966)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/campanological-problem-in-group-theory-ii/8C399AE3C6A1B7400EE98B60FBA0EF97), which I shall state in full below ('Lemma 3' refers to the numbering in [[1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X09000776)] and not in [[3](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society/article/abs/campanological-problem-in-group-theory-ii/8C399AE3C6A1B7400EE98B60FBA0EF97)]).

> **Lemma 3** Let $G$ be a finite group, generated by two elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$, such that $(\alpha\beta)^2 = 1$. Then the Cayley graph $\Gamma = \Gamma(G, \{\alpha, \beta\})$ contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

In other words, note that the product of the generators above is an involution. In the proof for **Theorem 2**, the authors invoke the use of **Lemma 3** as follows:

> It is a well known consequence from the classification of finite simple groups, that every non-Abelian finite simple group can be generated by two elements, one of which is an involution. Therefore **Lemma 3** is applicable, and for every non-Abelian finite simple group produces a generating set $S$, with $|S| = 2$, such that the corresponding Cayley graph contains a Hamiltonian cycle.

Finally, I can state my question in full: **Lemma 3** requires that the *product* of the generators to be an involution, however we are only given that *one of the generators* is an involution; is the product necessarily an involution then? How exactly is **Lemma 3** invoked?

Many thanks for your time and for reading this far! :-)

Comment: The context is not uninteresting, but for the benefit of those who do not necessarily want to know it all, perhaps you could have stated your question immediately. In fact, as David Craven shows in his answer, it is moderately easy, becuase you can just change generators to make $\alpha\beta$ the original involutory generator.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your feedback; I will edit the question accordingly.

Comment: But the question at the top now is not what you want to ask.  The answer to that question, in the case when $G$ is a finite nonabelian simple group, is never. What you need to prove is that, if $G = \langle a,b \rangle$ with $a$ an involution, then there exist $c,d \in G$ such that $G = \langle c,d \rangle$ and $cd$ is an involution. Proof: put $c=b$ and $d = b^{-1}a$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You make a good point; adjusted working accordingly. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: OK, now the answer is always, as I explained in my previous comment, and David Craven showed in his answer.

Comment: Thanks again @DerekHolt, for helping improve the readability of my post. I kept it in a ‘question’ format and did not include the solution in the edit, so that other users can upvote the solutions and comments given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a$ and $b$ are elements of $G$ such that $G=\langle a,b\rangle$, and $c=ab$, then
$$G=\langle a,b\rangle=\langle a,c\rangle=\langle b,c\rangle.$$
Thus one can choose any two of $a$, $b$ and $ab$ to be a generating set.

Comment: I'm not sure I necessarily understand; suppose that $G = \langle a, b \rangle$ and that $a$ is an involution. How does the above imply that $ab$ is an involution? To invoke Lemma 3, I require $G = \langle a, b \rangle$ such that $ab$ is an involution. Please excuse me if my question wasn't clear or if I am missing something obvious (perhaps it's time I have a break...)

Comment: @boolean Suppose $G$ is generated by $a$,$b$ where $b$ is an involution. Let $c=a^{-1}b$. Then clearly $G$ is generated by $a$,$c$ and $ac$ is an involution.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah! Staring me right in the face - thanks go both to you and David. I feel silly now :-)

Comment: @boolean Thanks for the link to that paper, cause that looks interesting to me. I played around with Hamiltonian paths/circuits on Cayley graphs in the context of twisty puzzles like the Rubik's Cube, and wrote up a page about that [here](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/hamilton.htm). Later Hamiltonian circuits were found for the 2x2x2 and 3x3x3 Rubik's Cube by [cuBer Bruce](https://bruce.cubing.net/). In the cubing world these are called the Devil's algorithm, as opposed to God's algorithm which is the optimal solution for every position.